# How does locking work in an Oracle transaction?

Tags: sql, oracle

In transaction

If I lock 2 datas (a and b)

And then commit once only

Will both of the locked data be commited? Or will it commit only one of the data (latest lock data)?

Comment: Did you tried something? Post the SQL statements. It will be much clearer and possible you'll find the solution self;)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you lock a row, make some changes; lock another row, make some changes and then commit, the commit will commit all the changes. Technically you have a single transaction.